# Change default URL on bitnami EC2 application

Tags: wordpress, apache2, amazon-ec2, bitnami

I'm running wordpress on a micro EC2 instance using a [bitnami AMI](http://bitnami.org/stack/wordpress) (ami-8333ffea to be exact) but I think this question applies to any bitnami cloud application. I've designated an Elastic IP and mapped a subdomain to the instance (e.g., blog.example.com). So far, so good.

Now I can access the blog but the URLs all contain '/wordpress' (blog.example.com/wordpress/.../). Bitnami has [documentation](http://wiki.bitnami.org/Applications/BitNami_Wordpress_Stack#How_to_change_the_default_URL.3f) (click 'Cloud Image/Bitnami Hoting' tab) for fixing this but I've tried following it several times without success. I make the changes, the site still works but '/wordpress' is still there taunting me. The machine is running Apache2 and the instructions all seem to make sense. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably the WordPress siteurl setting was not updated. The following command has to be executed:

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/mysql/bin/mysql -u root -p -e "use bitnami_wordpress; update wp_options set option_value='http://blog.example.com' where option_name='siteurl' or option_name='home'"
```

Make sure that you substitute "blog.example.com" in the example above with your own domain name.

And after changing the httpd.conf file, the Apache web server should be restarted:

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart apache
```

You can take a look at the [BitNami Cloud Hosting article](http://wiki.bitnami.org/BitNami_Cloud_Hosting/howto/Assign_a_Custom_Domain_to_Your_Server) explaining how to assign a custom domain to your server, you can directly jump to the 6th section.

If you have BitNami specific questions, consider visiting BitNami Support page [bitnami.org/support](http://bitnami.org/support).

Comment: EXCELLENT. SUCCESS. The link you posted is so much more informative then all the other sources I found, and there were so many of them to sift through. As someone who doesn't know much but is learning, this was extremely helpful (other methods did not mention setting up a virtual host). After following your advice, all I had to do was add the perma-link code to the .htaccess file and everything was working great again (and without '/wordpress'!). Thanks again!